# Weight paint Doesn'paint everywhere I want

Tags: weight-painting

I didn't find the answer in the asking questions, so I explain my problem.
I try to weight paint to open and close the mouth of a fish, but it doesn't paint well. As you can see in the scrennshot, for example, I wanted to bluish the lower lip in order to move it separately from the upper one...
[image]
Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Press Z (wireframe mode in 2.79) and try again.

Comment: The wireframe mode doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: I precise that I used the shark armature from blender, and tried to change weight paint.

Comment: Here is my project : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6736" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6736/)